# How to use SIM800l in esp8266 in micropython

Tags: esp8266, gsm, micropython

I have a code :

1. from machine import UART, Pin
2. 
3. TERMINATION_CHAR = '\x1a'
4. 
5. TXD_PIN = 1
6. RXD_PIN = 3
7. RST_PIN = 5
8. 
9. RST = Pin(RST_PIN, mode=Pin.OUT)
10. RST.value(0)
11. uart = UART(1, baudrate=115200, pins=(TXD_PIN, RXD_PIN))
12. RST.value(1)

But it is showing a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: extra keyword arguments given
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Micropython [UART documentation](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.UART.html#machine-uart) :

On the **WiPy only** the following keyword-only parameter is supported: pins.

No other Micropython port supports "pins" keyword parameter on the UART constructor call.

So you need to remove the pins argument; also, you should use UART 0, since in the esp8266 UART 1 is used for debug output only:

```
uart = UART(0, baudrate=115200)
```

On the esp8266 you cannot change the pins used by UART0 or UART1, the pins are fixed for each UART. Refer for the documentation for your particular esp8266 board to find which pins are used for the UART.

Comment: Can you send me diagram of connection of esp82266 and sim800l

Answer (score 0):

The Sim800l GSM module draws an instantaneous current of around 2000 mAh when connecting to the network. If your power source cannot handle this power requirement, your GSM module won't be able to connect.